# Overlay is not shown with vuetify 3

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuetify.js

This is the example, taken from [vuetify sample](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/v3.0.0-alpha.7/packages/docs/src/examples/v-overlay/prop-absolute.vue)

```
<template>
  <v-row
    align="center"
    justify="center"
  >
    <v-card
      height="300"
      width="250"
    >
      <v-row justify="center">
        <v-btn
          color="success"
          class="mt-12"
          @click="overlay = !overlay"
        >
          Show Overlay
        </v-btn>

        <v-overlay
          :absolute="absolute"
          :value="overlay"
        >
          <v-btn
            color="success"
            @click="overlay = false"
          >
            Hide Overlay
          </v-btn>
        </v-overlay>
      </v-row>
    </v-card>
  </v-row>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data: () => ({
      absolute: true,
      overlay: false,
    }),
  }
</script>
```

This is the result I get:

[image]

The problem is that when I click the button, then nothing happens. As I am just learning vue and vuetify I can't understand what is wrong with this example. Could anyone help me?

Important: vue 3, vuetify 3.0.0-alpha.7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply need to change `:value="overlay"` to `v-model="overlay"`, like this:

```
<v-overlay
   :absolute="absolute"
   v-model="overlay"
/>
```

Result after change:

[image]

Comment: Could you explain the reason of wrong code in vuetify samples? It is the second time you help me with official examples. Are their examples still for vue 2?

Comment: These examples were made for Vue 2. Look at the date of last commit: `Latest commit c8bd4bd on 1 Sep 2020`

Comment: It's still in alpha state, some things may change in the future. For now even the live examples from vuetify docs are broken. Seems like nobody wants to update them.

Comment: Okay, I can take a look later.

Answer (score -2):

the overlay component probably won't look like much from the default code. It basically just appends a dark square over the screen with no content. So perhaps there's a CSS conflict happening on your page (unless of course there's errors in the console).

What are you expecting to see when clicking the button?

**Edit** Check this CodePen for working example:
https://codepen.io/monty9120/pen/JjNoxOe?editors=101

```
    <div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-row
      align="center"
      justify="center"
    >
      <v-card
        height="300"
        width="250"
      >
        <v-row justify="center">
          <v-btn
            color="success"
            class="mt-12"
            @click="overlay = !overlay"
          >
            Show Overlay
          </v-btn>
  
          <v-overlay
            :absolute="absolute"
            :value="overlay"
          >
            <v-btn
              color="success"
              @click="overlay = false"
            >
              Hide Overlay
            </v-btn>
          </v-overlay>
        </v-row>
      </v-card>
    </v-row>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

And then in the Script:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({
    absolute: true,
    overlay: false,
  }),
})
```

Be sure to include all the dependencies from the CodePen

Comment: What vue and vuetify version do you use in your example?

Comment: Veutify version 2.5.6
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.5.6/dist/vuetify.min.js

Vue version 2.6.14
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js

Comment: But the question is about vue 3 and vuetify 3.

Comment: @Pavel_K should be a huge deal since you're using pretty much a super basic feature here, it may have not changed in v3.